# How to set parameters for Describe() function?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python

I developed one tool  in arcgis using python code, in the process i used Describe(feature class) function to know the coordinate system of input feature class. I got success while compiling code, But i couldn't get how to set parameters for this function in tool(arcgis 10.0) designing.

I tried parameters as follow

```
Display  name:input feature class
Data type : coordinate system.
Type   : optional
Direction : input.
```

My problem is  while i'm selecting input feature class, i didn't get coordinate system of that feature class.

Please Suggest..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could use code validation to populate the parameter with the coordinate system of the feature class, using something like the following:

```python
def updateParameters(self):
    fc =  self.params[0].value #Change 0 to refer to parameter number of feature class
    if fc: #Check if value was specified
        #Change 1 to refer to parameter number of coordinate system
        self.params[1].value = arcpy.Describe(fc).SpatialReference.name
    return
```

Or the easiest way would be to just perform all of this in your actual code, and not worry about populating another parameter.